# How do you set up this Tricky u-sub?

Tags: calculus

Tricky u-sub.  Can you point me in the right direction?

$$\int{{x^3}\sqrt{5-2x^2}}dx$$

$u = 5-2x^2$

$ du = -4x dx$

Obviously, this does not match fully.

---

I tried breaking up the $x^3 = x*x^2$
 and I continued with:

$u=5-2x^2$

$2x^2 = 5-u$

$x^2=\frac{5-u}{2}$

But, I can't see how to make it all fit.

Am I on the right track?

[image]

Comment: In a later comment, you mention that your answer doesn't match the book's.  The only thing you seem to be missing from your work is that you can't have an integral of x end up being about u.  You have to change variables back to the original x.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Am I on the right track?

You're doing fine!

So you have $u=5-2x^2$ which gives $x^2=\frac{5-u}{2}$ and from $\mbox{d}u=-4x\,\mbox{d}x$ you get $x\,\mbox{d}x=-\tfrac{1}{4}\mbox{d}u$.

Now perform the substitution:
$$\int{{x^3}\sqrt{5-2x^2}}\,\mbox{d}x = -\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{5-u}{2}\sqrt{u}\,\mbox{d}u= -\frac{1}{8}\int \left(5\sqrt{u}-u^{\tfrac{3}{2}}\right)\,\mbox{d}u = \ldots$$

Comment: Ok, that's exactly where I got to.   Now, I just integrate the basic binomial, right?   I edited the original post with my work.  This did not match the solutions in the book I am working with.  Theirs was all a very simple integral with a single term.

Comment: @JackOfAll That would have been something to include from the beginning.

Comment: @JackOfAll The steps you added are all fine! Now replace $u$ by $5-2x^2$ and you are done. If the answer doesn't look the same; they may have simplified a bit further.

Comment: The answer in the book was nothing like mine.  They reduced the entire integral to something like $-\frac{1}{4}\int{u^\frac{2}{3}du}$

Comment: @JackOfAll - Unless you supply more details, we cannot guess what is going on with your "something like"s. I strongly suspect you are mis-interpreting what the book is saying. But again, without details, I can't be sure.

Comment: @JackOfAll, you can always check your answer by taking the derivative, and seeing if you can manipulate the resulting expression to match the integrand.

Comment: I found the official answer.  They turned the entire thing into $-\frac{1}{4}\int{u^\frac{1}{3}}$      Any idea how they got that ??

Answer (score 2):

By your idea we have

- $u = 5-2x^2\implies x^2=\frac{5-u}{2}$
- $ du = -4x dx\implies xdx=-\frac14 du $

then

$$\int{{x^3}\sqrt{5-2x^2}}dx=\int{\frac{5-u}{2}\sqrt{u}}\left(-\frac14\right) du$$

Answer (score 1):

You've done all the hard work. Doing some rearranging, you obtain
$$\int x^3 \sqrt{5-2x^2}\, dx = \int -\frac{1}{4} x^2 \sqrt{5-2x^2} \cdot (-4x)\, dx = \int -\frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{5-u}{2} \sqrt{u}\, du$$
This last integral can be computed as usual by considering powers of $u$.

Answer (score 1):

**Another approach:**

We can write the integrand as
\begin{align*}
{x^3}\sqrt{5-2x^2}&=-\tfrac12x(5-2x^2)\sqrt{5-2x^2}+\tfrac52x\sqrt{5-2x^2}&&\text{then}\\[5pt]
\int{x^3}\sqrt{5-2x^2}dx&=-\frac12\int x\left(5-2x^2\right)^{3/2}dx+\frac52\int x\left(5-2x^2\right)^{1/2}dx\\[5pt]
&=\color{red}{\frac1{20}\left(5-2x^2\right)-\frac5{12}\left(5-2x^2\right)^{3/2}+C}
\end{align*}